# Using HttpClient from scriptcs script

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, scriptcs

I am trying to use `HttpClient` from a scriptcs script but experiencing some issues. First, I wasn't able to even install a `Microsoft.Net.Http` NuGet package because this package requires NuGet 2.8, and scriptcs was installed with NuGet.Core.dll version 2.7. But after fetching a prerelease version of scriptcs from MyGet (version 0.10 alpha) Microsoft.Net.Http was successfully installed. However, an attempt to instantiate HttpClient causes an error:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'HttpClient' does not exist
>   in the namespace 'System.Net.Http' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

I tried with both "using" directive or specifying the qualified type name. No luck. I can trace Microsoft.Net.Http is loaded.

Here's the code that fails:

```
using System.Net.Http;
var client = new HttpClient();
```

UPDATE. Found the problem. I thought that referencing Microsoft.Net.Http would be sufficient. But in .NET 4.5 I also had to reference System.Net.Http:

```
#r "System.Net.Http"
```

Now it works!

Comment: Silly question, are you targeting the correct framework, e.g. 4.5?

Comment: Hmm, can I control the framework? Didn't find anything about in command line options.

Comment: But it looks like it grabs old System.Net.Http stuff even though it says it successfully loaded Microsoft.Net.Http.

Comment: Could you check if you had the assembly referenced in the project?

Comment: I've found the problem: I also had to execute #r "System.Net.Http"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought that referencing Microsoft.Net.Http would be sufficient. But in .NET 4.5 I also had to reference System.Net.Http:

```
#r "System.Net.Http"
```

This solved the issue.